# Как заменить значения в столбце DataFrame на значения из другого DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Не могу решить одну задачку. У меня есть DataFrame, он состоит из номеров IMSI. IMSI- это международный идентификатор мобильного абонента (индивидуальный номер абонента).

IMSI=MCC+MNC+MSIN

MCC = Mobile Country Code (код страны), 3 цифры

MNC = Mobile Network Code (код сети), 1–3 цифры

MSIN = Mobile Station Identificator Number (код станции, "вышки") – x1-x10, 9–10 цифр - это не пригодиться

[Тут справочники по всем MCC и MNC](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/FLmAE7qJmXl97Q)

Для России это примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что у России MCC=250

Также есть мой DataFrame, в котором есть список IMSI.

[Он тут](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/dp2FhWxwVOkjVQ)

Примерно такое в нем:

[image: DataSet c IMSI]

В чем суть задачи, я пытаюсь парсить IMSI в моей таблице для создания столбца ['MCC'] и ['MNC'].
С созданием ['MCC'] проблем не возникло. Код ниже:

```
subset=pd.read_csv('imsi.csv',sep=';')
mcc=pd.read_csv('mcc-mnc-operator-list.csv',sep=';')

subset["IMSI"]=subset["IMSI"].astype('str')
subset['MCC']=subset["IMSI"].str.extract(r"(\d{3})")
subset['MCC']=subset['Mobile Country Code'].astype('int')
dict_mcc=dict(zip(mcc['MCC'],mcc['Country']))
subset['Государство']=subset['MCC'].map(dict_mcc)
```

Вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как сделать столбец ['MNC'] у меня не получается. Тут значения могут быть от 1-3, и тут весь затык. Как это парсить, не могу понять.

Comment: ну я увидел, что в вашей таблице MNC от 1 до 99. при этом, в числе MCCMNC это 4 и 5 цифры (с ведущим нулём). не понимаю, в чем у вас трудность.

Comment: @strawdog, MNC от 1 до 998 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте делать объединение по столбцу `MCCMNC` из справочника и соответствующей подстрокой из `IMSI` в рабочей таблице.

```
mcc = pd.read_csv("mcc-mnc-operator-list.csv", sep=";", dtype={"MNC":str}, encoding="latin-1")
df = pd.read_csv("imsi.scv", index_col=0, parse_dates=["Дата создания"], dtype={"IMSI": str})

mcc2 = mcc.drop(columns="Network / operator").drop_duplicates()

res = df.assign(MCCMNC=df["IMSI"].str[:6]).merge(mcc2).append(df.assign(MCCMNC=df["IMSI"].str[:5]).merge(mcc2))

# let's take care of unmatched records
ids = res["IMSI"]
res.append(df.query("IMSI not in @ids"))
```

результат:

```
In [153]: res
Out[153]:
          Дата создания             IMSI MCCMNC    MCC  MNC Country
0   2021-01-02 16:51:20  250992221922154  25099  250.0   99  Russia
1   2021-01-29 16:34:01  250992212048656  25099  250.0   99  Russia
2   2021-01-02 14:18:48  250992212446822  25099  250.0   99  Russia
3   2021-01-28 17:44:58  250992222903343  25099  250.0   99  Russia
4   2021-01-28 17:05:03  250992101281658  25099  250.0   99  Russia
..                  ...              ...    ...    ...  ...     ...
68  2021-01-29 10:12:40  250621000406994    NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN
132 2021-01-29 16:05:06  250621004596443    NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN
136 2021-01-02 13:39:14  250621000406994    NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN
157 2021-01-02 12:09:55  250621000474943    NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN
409 2021-01-02 12:50:28  250621001335819    NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN

[603 rows x 6 columns]
```

PS строки с `NaN`-ми соответствуют тем `IMSI`, для которых в справочнике не существует соответствующих `MCC` и `MNC`, как, например `250` и `62`.

Comment: спасибо! Все получилось, то что надо